# css positioning, image is getting cut

Tags: html, css

I am stuck. AS you see in screenshot [image]

I marked , I would like to put PNG-logo on top of that div and to get that result.
[image]

However, I tried to use absolute positioning, but logo is getting cut[image]

So how to do that?

```
<div id="bodyWrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="topRow">
                            <div id="storeLogo"> 
                                <a href="/"></a><img src="/images/original.png" width="200px" height="180px" alt="Свадебный салон" title="Свадебный салон Золушка"/> </div>
```

and the css

```
#header .header-wrapper {
background: url(/images/bg_1.png) repeat-x top left; }
#header .header-wrapper .header_menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e4e4;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 9px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 9px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08); }
#header #storeLogo {
float: left;
  top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 0; }
#header #storeLogo a {
  display: inline-block; }
#header .topRow {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; }
#header .topRow .languages {
  margin-right: 22px; }
#header .topRow .currencies {
  margin-right: 47px; }
#header .topRow .currencies,
#header .topRow .languages {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  color: #888888;
  margin-top: 49px; }
```

Comment: The white wrapper div might have `overflow:hidden` applied to it, but we can't tell without seeing the necessary `CSS`

Comment: post your html code of top row in which you want to put your logo

Comment: overflow: hidden;
position: relative;

Comment: Removing `overflow:hidden` should fix this problem.

Comment: removing doesnt fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved due to my mistake.
solve:
as Nick R said, the wrapper has had overflow:hidden option.
there were other div-s with the such option. removing the `overflow:hidden` from right div - fixed. Thank you.